# Why doesn't cursor change to pointer/hand on Tabs, Pagination, Dropdown Toggle etc in angular-ui-bootstrap?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have to add the following code:

`<style type="text/css">a {cursor:pointer;}</style>`

to make cursor change to pointer/hand on links for Tabs, Pagination, Dropdown Toggle etc.. in angular-ui-bootstrap.

Why doesn't it change to pointer by default? Is this done intentionally? this is not the normal case in pure bootstrap.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 27):

Does the `<a>` have a `href` attribute? The cursor won't change if it doesn't...